# Exporting Data into CSV file and retrieving file name

Tags: vba, excel, export, filenames, export-to-csv

So I have already exported data using a CSV file, but as of now it is just raw data. I am trying to dsiplay the file name that it is from and the Sheet name. Here is my code so far from exporting the data. The following macro exports the data from an open excel sheet, I just run the macro and exports the data into a new workbook. Now I just want to display the file name and sheet name from the source that I exported from on the new CSV file that is created.

Sub testexport()

```
 ' export Macro

Range("B7:E26,B39:E138").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"Y:\SQCData.csv" _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The following range that it displays contains my data. Now my question is... How do I display the file name and the sheet name on the same excel sheet after it has been exported?

Comment: How are you naming your CSV exported files? Are they based on the sheetname?

Comment: Kind of, I want to get the workbook name as well as sheet name in a column on top and then display data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tweak this

```
Sub CopyPasteBetween2Books()

Dim wb As Workbook

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B7:E26,B39:E138").Copy
    wbname2 = ThisWorkbook.Name
    wsname2 = ActiveSheet.Name
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    wbname = "Y:\SQCData.csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wbname
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Y:\SQCData.csv")
    wb.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = wbname2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = wsname2


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and it only displays the new workbook name and sheet that is created. Sorry I should have clarified, I want the workbook name and sheetname from the workbook that I exported from.

Comment: @adit123 edited code to get the source workbook/worksheet names

Comment: This code has some problems. So I basically have a template workbook, that when you press an object on the template it opens up a specific directory. Then, I choose the excel file that I want to export the data from and press another object on my ribbon that exports the data into a worksheet. The code that you typed only displayed the name of my template , and it displayed the source sheet number. Also the data was not successfully exported. It was just a blank workbook that opened up with only the name of my template workbook and the sheet name from the source workbook.

Comment: I believe the code is fine as presented with the original question.  That question being you had a workbook to export and needed the name of that workbook and sheet name.  The problem is now you're explaining the code would actually reside in a different workbook (template) and not the workbook that exported data is coming from.  So the range being copied is from the template which I'm assuming that range is blank.  Step through the code to confirm and also see what each line doing and you should be able to tweak to take into account the template workbook.

Comment: That makes sense. So even though both of those workbooks are active and I run the macro that extracts data from the worksheet I am currently on, it still somehow receives data from the template workbook? Should I try to modify it with the code I had before to select the data on the active sheet?

Comment: @mrbungle - you dont need `wb.activate`. Refer to the required cell of wb directly.

Comment: @PankajJaju  and mrbungle I am currently tweaking the code. I will let you guys know what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetFileNameandSheet()

' assign variables
Dim strFolder  As String
Dim strFile    As String
Dim latestFile As String
Dim dtLast  As Date

strFolder = "C:\MyFolder\"          ' sets search path - put the directory where you saved the file here - enclose in quotes
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*", vbNormal)  ' looks for ,csv  files only

 '  This loops through files to find latest modified date
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile) > dtLast Then
            dtLast = FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile)
            latestFile = strFolder & strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

' The following will write the latest file name and sheet to 2 cells on the active sheet
Range("XX") = latestFile         ' writes the latest .csv file name in your folder - substitute the cell location were you want the data
Range("XY") = ActiveSheet.Name   'writs the Active Sheet name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry I should have clarified, I want to display the workbook name and sheet name of the workbook that I exported from onto the CSV file.